# Can someone tell me if my junction box can support a fan?

Tags: junction

[image]

There's no visible text or a sticker in there so I cannot determine if this is supported by a joist. I also do not have access to the attic.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no sticker or if it's not stamped that it's "ceiling fan rated", then it's not.  That junction box is not rated for a ceiling fan. It appears to be screwed into a joist so remove it and replace with a junction box rated for a ceiling fan. With only one cable entering the box, replacing it should be fairly easy. Those two bracket mounting tabs in the front of the box will not support a fan.